# How to use HTTPS GET command with TIdTCPClient?

Tags: delphi, ssl, tcp, indy

I'm using Indy `TIdTCPClient` to call HTTPS but the server is timing out waiting for my HTTP command. In Wireshark I can see the TLS handshake is done, but none of the `WriteLn()` commands are responded by the server.

I know using `TIdHTTP` will be easier, but I have another purpose. Below is the attached code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sid, result: string;
  lParam: TStringList;
  TCPC: TIdTCPClient;
  OnSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  begin
    lParam := TStringList.Create;
    TCPC := TIdTCPClient.Create();
    OnSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
    try
      OnSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
      OnSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
      OnSSL.UseNagle := True;
      OnSSL.PassThrough := False;

      TCPC.Host := 'xxxxxxx.edu';
      TCPC.Port := 443;
      TCPC.ConnectTimeout := 100000;
      TCPC.ReadTimeout := 500000;
      TCPC.IOHandler := OnSSL;
      TCPC.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
      TCPC.Connect;

      try
        logging(TCPC.IOHandler.ReadLn);
        if TCPC.IOHandler.Connected then
        begin
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('GET / HTTP/1.1', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Host: xxxxxxx.edu', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Connection: keep-alive', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Pragma: no-cache', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Cache-Control: no-cache', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.Write('sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.Writeln('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Sec-Fetch-Site: none', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Sec-Fetch-User: ?1', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Sec-Fetch-Dest: document', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
          TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
        end;

        result := TCPC.IOHandler.AllData(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);

        logging(result);
      finally
        TCPC.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      lParam.Free;
      OnSSL.Free;
      TCPC.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

- wasting memory to create an unused `TStringList` object.
- enabling obsolete SSL v2 and v3, which are no longer secure.
- calling `IOHandler.ReadLn()` before sending the HTTP request. The HTTP/S protocol *does not* involve an initial greeting.
- making an erroneous `IOHandler.Write()` call for the `sec-ch-ua` header. It should be using `IOHandler.WriteLn()` instead.
- requesting that compression of the HTTP body is allowed, when you are not actually prepared to decompress it.
- not terminating the HTTP request correctly. You need to send a blank line after the headers. This is the reason for the server timeout error.
- using `IOHandler.AllData()` to read the HTTP response, which will read until the server disconnects, but you are also enabling HTTP keepalives, which asks the server *not* to disconnect. Even without HTTP keepalives (since you are destroying the connection after reading the HTTP response, using a keepalive makes no sense anyway), `AllData()` is still the wrong way to read an HTTP response. (I've [posted many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) in the past regarding the *proper* way to read an HTTP response).
- redundant use of the `IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property *and* `AByteEncoding` parameters.  You don't need to use the latter when using the former, and vice versa.

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Result: string;
  TCPC: TIdTCPClient;
  OnSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  TCPC := TIdTCPClient.Create();
  try
    OnSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(TCPC);
    OnSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    OnSSL.PassThrough := False;
    OnSSL.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
    
    TCPC.Host := 'xxxxxxx.edu';
    TCPC.Port := 443;
    TCPC.ConnectTimeout := 100000;
    TCPC.ReadTimeout := 500000;
    TCPC.IOHandler := OnSSL;

    TCPC.Connect;
    try
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('GET / HTTP/1.1');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Host: xxxxxxx.edu');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Connection: close');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Pragma: no-cache');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Cache-Control: no-cache');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36');
      TCPC.IOHandler.Writeln('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Sec-Fetch-Site: none');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Sec-Fetch-User: ?1');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Sec-Fetch-Dest: document');
      //TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn('Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9');
      TCPC.IOHandler.WriteLn();

      // I'm leaving this here only because I don't have the time right now
      // to rewrite it properly. Go read my previous answers on this topic...
      Result := TCPC.IOHandler.AllData();
    
      logging(Result);
    finally
      TCPC.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    TCPC.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, you are correct that using `TIdHTTP` would be *much* simpler, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Result: string;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  OnSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
  try
    OnSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(TCPC);
    OnSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    
    HTTP.ConnectTimeout := 100000;
    HTTP.ReadTimeout := 500000;
    HTTP.IOHandler := OnSSL;

    HTTP.Request.Connection := 'close';
    HTTP.Request.Pragma := 'no-cache';
    HTTP.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
    HTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36';
    HTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9';
    HTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'en-US,en;q=0.9';
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['sec-ch-ua'] :='" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"';
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['sec-ch-ua-mobile'] := '?0';
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['sec-ch-ua-platform'] := '"Windows"';
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests'] := '1';
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Sec-Fetch-Site'] := 'none';
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Sec-Fetch-Mode'] := 'navigate';
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Sec-Fetch-User'] := '?1';
    HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Sec-Fetch-Dest'] := 'document';

    // if you want to support compressed responses, assign a
    // TIdZLibCompressorBase-derived component to the
    // TIdHTTP.Compressor property...

    Result := HTTP.Get('https://xxxxxxx.edu/');
    
    logging(Result);
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

There are very few reasons to use `TIdTCPClient` directly rather than `TIdHTTP`.

Comment: Thanks Remy that's very kind of you to do this comprehensive explanation. And I can understand all you said. I have fix it. and use readln instead of alldata. and I can receive the package. :)

Answer (score 0):

To start with you need to send a blank line to mark the end of the HTTP metadata/headers.

```
TCPC.IOHandler.Writeln('',IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

Comment: It works.... i just also remove secfetch* meta data from the meta data hearders.